# Are "final decision" and "last decision" interchangeable?

Tags: differences

Looking into a dictionary entry for *last*, I come up with:

> 1) Final, ultimate, coming after all others of its kind.
>   2) Most recent, latest, last so far.

Looking up *final*:

> 1) last; ultimate
>   2) Conclusive; decisive

Now I'm wondering what's the difference between *final decision* and *last decision,* were one to be strict and pedantic.

My theory:

*last decision* - ambiguous - may mean "final decision" or "most recent decision in a chain of decisions yet to follow
*final decision* - not ambiguous - means only "final decision"

Am I correct here or am I somehow mistaken?

Comment: Last decision is not necessary final. It is the last so far in series of decisions. So yeah I think you pretty much nail it ;-)

Comment: Except that *last* is also used definitively in the sense of final/ ultimate: The Last Supper; The Last Testament, off the top of the mind.

Comment: You are right; have you seen the film "the final decision"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It honestly depends on context.  If you were to say

> "That was my last decision." vs
>
> "That was my final decision."

you are likely to mean two different things, as you describe in your question.  However, consider

> "This will be my last decision." vs
>
> "This will be my final decision."

In this context the former statement implies the latter, so the meaning of the two phrases is the same, whether you mean final in the sense of "not going to change" or final in the sense of "last in a series".