# "former" vs "last" as in "my former, only and last husband"

Tags: meaning, differences, emphasis

I was reading a book and found this expression:

> [...] my former, only and last husband.

Could anyone tell me what are the differences between *former* and *last* in this case?
Also, would ***former and only*** suffice to express this idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are "final decision" and "last decision" interchangeable?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68137/are-final-decision-and-last-decision-interchangeable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you know the definitions of *former*, *only*, and *last*.

They all mean what they usually mean. However, when used in series like this, it serves as a means of *intensification*. It does clarify that she has no intention or ever remarrying, but it's *emphatic*. It is a variation on the more common *first, last, and only* series.

Someone who hears "He is my only child" will know that the child was also the first and last child. However, "*He is my first, last, and only child*" makes it crystal clear that the speaker feels strongly about *something* (without context, I'd guess her child was enough for one lifetime.)

Similarly, my *former* and *only* husband clearly means he was her *last* husband; *only* and *last* means *former* husband as well, but the three in a series indicates something about the mood of the speaker. Clearly she means to say something not only about her husband, but also about the institution of marriage. If not, she could simply have referred to him as her ex-husband.

examples of this use:

> - *First, last, and only* structural selectors provides you with *in-depth* training on Web.
> - The First, Last and Only All-Black Ranger Unit
> - The First, Last and Only Thing You Need to Hear
> - Mandalay Bay is the first, last and only resort.
> - Live Each Day as if it were Your First, Last, and Only Day
> - The first, last, and only choice for the Senate...

Comment: I disagree that _only and last_ means _former_ as well... "She is the only and last girl I will ever love!" certainly does not mean that the love is over now. Whether _former_ is implied depends more on the verb tense than on the uniqueness (only) or ordinality (last) of the husband, love or child. I _do_ agree with the interpretation of the mood of the author from the use of adjectives with _similar_ meanings though.

Answer (score 2):

Former -> Happened earlier in time but only relative to the current point.

Last -> Happened earlier in time (from the current point) and all other instances happened prior to this.

| Joe | Jack | Jim | John |

Here [Joe, Jack, Jim, John] are former husbands but only [John] is the last one.

When you look at the context (*former, only and last*) then the *last* also indicates that the person in question is referring to the future: there will not be another husband after this point in time.

> Also, would "former and only" suffice to express this idea?

Without explicitly adding the *last* there is ambiguity about whether or not you mean that it was the only husband *so far* or *forever*.

Answer (score 2):

former – (adjective) having once, or previously, been

last – (adjective) coming after all others in a series

Former means he was previously her husband but is now not. Last means there she will take no more husbands in the future.

Comment: Yes, but it's worth mentioning that *last* can also have the more specific subsense *coming after all others in a series **extending up to but not including the present***. As in, "I admit my last comment was complete rubbish, but this next one is absolutely brilliant".

Comment: To say he was her former and only husband already implies he was her last husband in the sense of being the most recent previous husband, so last here would only be used to mean last in the sense that he is her final husband - assuming it's not a poorly worded tautology.

Comment: very true. good points.

Answer (score 0):

I believe "my former, only and last husband" does not necessarily indicate the speaker will take no husbands in future -that is just not Shakespearean!

**Former husband**: they were in fact married once but no longer are betrothed

**Last husband**: he was indeed the last she married but it may or may not address the future, but only her intent.

IRL, Elizabeth Taylor often referred to Richard Burton as both a former husband, and her last husband (twice).  A novel is a novel is a novel, and depending on the emphasis by the character, stating this man is her "my former, only and last husband" is a hint of foreshadowing.

As for *would "former and only" suffice to express this idea?*, it could, if she was exhaling her last breath